# Debug the execution of a git hook

Tags: git, groovy, githooks

How would I setup my development environment to catch breakpoints and debug the execution of a git hook? Lets say the hook in focus is pre-commit and that the following groovy script needs to be debugged?

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy

// Arguments for git log command.
def logArgs = ['max-count': '1', 'pretty': 'format:%an commited %s {%h}']

// Invoke git log command.
def gitLog = logArgs.inject(['git', 'log']) { cmd, k, v -> 
    cmd << "--$k=$v" 
}.execute()

// Get git log message to be used as notification message.
def message = gitLog.text
println(message)
```

And what would I do see the output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you do the following:

1. Create an `actual_hook_file.groovy` and put all you hook code there.
2. In you existing hook use only: `groovy -Xdebug -Xnoagent -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=9090,server=n,suspend=y actual_hook_file.groovy`
3. Trigger hook
4. Attach to the JVM on 9090 port with debugging tool (`Remote Java Application in Eclipse`, for example).
5. Debug!

So, the idea is to run JVM in debug mode (it may be a bit differ for Java, than for Groovy). The simpliest way to achieve this is via wrapper file.

Comment: btw, i found out that I had to switch server=n to a new position just before the address=9090 and adjust my firewall accordingly. It would otherwise fail with a connection refused. Also, suspend=n had to be set to =y, so that jdwp would wait for my eclipse remote debugging. Finally, I've found out that address can be prefix with a host ip like this: address=127.0.0.1:9090

Comment: Sorry, I've copied debug string from my config. Of course `suspend` should be `y`. I'll edit the answer. But `address` and `server` ordering should not matter.